# The number of ways in which $n$ different things can be distributed into $r$ different groups is coefficient of $x^n$ in $n!(e^x-1)^r$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, generating-functions

This is the question of combination.

I have tried this but how can the binomial expansion can result our need?
How we can proof the  formula:

> The number of ways in which n different things can be distributed into
>   $r$ different groups is coefficient of $x^n$ in $n!(e^x-1)^r$?

Comment: $n!(e^x-1)$ is an expression that is independent of $r$, are you sure you stated the question correctly? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 also, learn mathjax to type maths on this site.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh , there's an $r$ in the expression, maybe it has been edited since you originally commented.

Comment: Yes...I have edited that..after siong Thye Goh commented